# How can multiple kernels update a shared Association object?

Tags: bugs, parallelization, associations

In the examples below, the variable `status` is an `Association` object that is supposed to be shared by three concurrent kernels.

The assignment `status[$KernelID] = 1` fails if I run it within `ParallelEvaluate`:

```
status = <||>;
SetSharedVariable[status];
ParallelEvaluate[status[$KernelID] = 1;];
status
```

> ```
> Set::noval: Symbol status in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
>
> Set::noval: Symbol status in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
>
> Set::noval: Symbol status in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
>
> <||>
> ```

An equivalent assignment works fine if I run it outside of `ParallelEvaluate`, as shown below.  (**NB:** In the snippet below, I use `ParallelEvaluate` only to get the values of `$KernelID` for the various kernels; the assignments to `status` happen outside `ParallelEvaluate`).

```
status = <||>;
SetSharedVariable[status];
Scan[(status[#] = 1) &, ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID]];
status
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1|>
> ```

Is there a way to share an `Association` object among all kernels in such a way that each kernel can modify the object?

FWIW, I am immediately interested in the use-case where each kernel assigns only to the key corresponding to its `$KernelID`.

---

**UPDATE:** FWIW, the problem seems to be specific to `Association`s; a similar scenario using a list instead of an association works fine:

```
statusList = ConstantArray[Null, Max[ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID]]];
SetSharedVariable[statusList];
ParallelEvaluate[statusList[[$KernelID]] = 1;];
statusList
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1}
> ```

(This looks more and more like a bug to me...  In this case, I suppose I should specify that I'm using 10.4.1.0 Linux x86 (64-bit).)

Comment: I did this a while back, but the difference there, perhaps, was that I was using `ParallelSubmit` and ``Parallel`Developer`QueueRun[]``. I'll see if I can piece together a workaround from the developer stuff. Also it complains that `status` is protected for me, which definitely suggests this is a bug.

Comment: With version 11.0.1, I get a different error message from the subkernels: `Set::wrsym :  Symbol status is Protected.` FWIW, `ParallelEvaluate[Attributes[status]]` returns a list with a bunch of `{Protected}` entries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I'm pretty sure this is a bug but here's why I think it happens and here's a workaround:

We'll do the setup:

```
status = <||>;
SetSharedVariable[status];
```

Then check the `OwnValues`:

```
In[354]:= ParallelEvaluate[OwnValues[status]]

Out[354]= {{HoldPattern[status] :> 
   Parallel`Client`CallBack[status]}, {HoldPattern[status] :> 
   Parallel`Client`CallBack[status]}, {HoldPattern[status] :> 
   Parallel`Client`CallBack[status]}, {HoldPattern[status] :> 
   Parallel`Client`CallBack[status]}}
```

From past digging in the `` Parallel`Developer `` context I think that's just a handler that the subkernel sees and then realizes "oh, I should pull the value from the parent kernel". This then breaks the `sym[key]=val` assignment pattern of associations. Of course there are other handlers in place to do setting synchronization, so I thought it might be worth trying `AssociateTo`. And that does in fact work:

```
In[355]:= ParallelEvaluate[AssociateTo[status, $KernelID -> 1]]

Out[355]= {Null, Null, Null, Null}

In[356]:= status

Out[356]= <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1|>
```

This also seems to makes sense for why `Part` can do the assignment. It's a) older and b) a proper symbol that the subkernel can check for. But of course I know nearly nothing about parallel kernels so that's just how I conceive of it.

In any case, to summarize, I think it's a bug and `AssociateTo` is a work-around.